# Solving a simple equation from Visual Studio Command Line Arguments (without using libraries)

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-arguments, equation

I want to prepare a c# program in visual studio, that acts as a simple equation solver. the equation solver runs from the command line args only with operators (+, -, *, /)

so the input would be in the format "calc 3X + 5 = 8"
and the output would give you X = 1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: What did you try? Could you  please show some code that you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

you have to create a parser => analyse the argument like

the parser does for example: https://github.com/mariuszgromada/MathParser.org-mXparser

without library i suggest to consider argument like "3 * X = 2"  and you loop every character if you find X its the variable and you could analyse * , -, + and / as operators:

```
foreach char c in args[0]
{
  if (c == '*')...
  if (c == '+')...
  if (c == 'X') => you have identify the variable
}
```

after you program the logic to resolve equation

its a beginning...
}

google Math parser or math equation parser

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing you need to do is write a *parser*. Depending on the complexity of your *grammar*, you may be able to do it by hand. However, if it is at all complex, you probably want to use a tool/library to do it.

Traditionally, you'd use a *lexer* to translate your input into a stream of *tokens*. Then you'd use another tool to parse the token stream using your grammar. The classic example of this is Unix's Lex and YACC toolset.

Antlr is a more modern (and easier to use) way of parsing input. And, it tends to get linked into every C# project. If you buy the main Antlr 4 book, I think your problem is one of the first examples.

Once you interpret and can understand the input, then you need to come up with a *solver* that will solve the equation.

Good luck.

By the way, "without using libraries" is a relative thing. If you use any part of the .NET framework, you are "using libraries". If you don't want to use any 3rd party libraries, read up on some if the things I mention to see how they do things (for example, how they use regular expressions) and go from there.

Once you have some code to show and have some problems, come back and ask a Stack Overflow-answerable question.